# How do I add "system setup" menu entry to grub?

Tags: grub2

How do I add the "system setup" option to my grub menu? I used to have it (in order to get into my UEFI/BIOS) but now it's missing.

Comment: Did it disappeared or did you reinstalled and now it's not there? If you reinstalled then you probably did it in Legacy mode. Either way, you should be able to access UEFI the usual way.

Comment: What did you do? What have you tried?